# Repeat a function X times in PHP

Tags: php

I want to hash the string 'text' three times.

```
md5(md5(md5('text')));
```

However, if I need to apply the function a lot more times this would be ridiculous to do. How can I repeat, for instance, the `md5()` function X times?

Comment: This has nothing to do with it. Please read both topics.

Comment: I said I gave this function as an example. And yes, I've tried that but it's different than my occasion. I'd prefer if you cannot help not to continue with this.

Comment: Nobody will continue with that attitude.

Comment: I don't understand where this is going. Fred -ii- have you tried what was posted in the topic you linked me?

Comment: This is not for passwords. Good? Of course I googled and as I did not find anything answering my question I took the liberty to ask a question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pass = "dongs";
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) $pass = md5($pass); //$pass will be hashed with md5() 5 times
```

[Example](http://3v4l.org/0XV9r)

Answer (score 4):

Using the example Fred -ii- linked to:

```
$i = 0;
$times_to_run = 16;
$hash = 'text';
while ($i++ < $times_to_run)
{
    $hash = md5($hash);
}
```

Comment: oh yeah, the one I was quickly shot down for you mean? I deleted all my comments. I know when I'm not wanted.

Comment: I'd vote up, but I'll have to wait till Stack lets me. I've used them all up for now.

Answer (score 1):

Or more universal:

```
function recursive_call($call, $iters, $variable){
    $result = $variable;
    for ($i=0; $i<$iters; $i++) $result = $call($result);
    return $result;
}
echo recursive_call('md5', 3, 'text');
```

And some magic:

```
function rcall2($call, $iters, $var){
    $result = $call($var);
    if ($iters > 1) $result = rcall2($call, $iters-1, $result);
    return $result;
}
rcall2('md5', 3, 'text');
```